# How to track speech Librosa (python library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, speech-recognition, librosa

So here's the thing, I'm developing a music player and trying to implement synced lyrics. So far I've been able to dynamically get the lyrics of the current playing track from google but now I need to convert that to a .lrc file (which is basically a file that contains the timestamps of the beginning of all the lines in the lyrics and the lyrics lines themselves). I did a lot of research and failed woefully until i came across a python library for audio analysis (Librosa) which i think has the potential to get me what I need. I've been able to work with ChatGpt to get some sort of result but it's a bit buggy.

The current version looks like this.

```
import math
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, USLT
import librosa
import os
import numpy as np
import pydub

def generate_lrc_file2(audio_file, lyrics_file):

    dur = pydub.utils.mediainfo(audio_file)["duration"]

    # Load the audio file using librosa
    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, duration=math.floor(float(dur)))

    # Load the lyrics from a text file
    with open(lyrics_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        lyrics = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    # Compute the beat timestamps using librosa

    tempo, beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)
    beat_times = librosa.frames_to_time(beat_frames, sr=sr)
    print(beat_times)

    # Compute the lyric timestamps
    lyric_times = np.linspace(0, beat_times[-1], len(lyrics) + 1)

    # Convert the lyric timestamps to LRC format
    lrc_timestamps = []
    for timestamp in lyric_times:
        minutes = int(timestamp // 60)
        seconds = int(timestamp % 60)
        hundredths = int((timestamp % 1) * 100)
        lrc_timestamps.append(f"[{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}.{hundredths:02}]")

    # Create the LRC file
    lrc_file = "song.lrc"
    with open(lrc_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for i in range(len(lyrics)):
            f.write(f"{lrc_timestamps[i]}{lyrics[i]}\n")
```

The code generate the lrc file alright but the problem is the timestamps are off. The song i used to test this, the first line is sang at `[00:16:xx]` but what was recorded by the code was `[00:00:00]` basically the very beginning. Now I'm not very familiar with Librosa library and it's internals but I suspect the issue has to do with tracking the beat with `librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)` which is essentially the very start of the song and so far I haven't been able to find how to track speech instead so it'll be awesome if someone could help with this or maybe suggest a different approach or even maybe some more audio manipulation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The task of finding at what times the lyrics of a song occur is known as *Lyrics Alignment* / *Lyrics-to-Audio Alignment*. The alignment can be on different granularity levels, for example phoneme, word or lyrical line level (your case).

The task is a widely researched topic in the field of Music Information Retrieval, going back at least to 2008.

The task has featured multiple times as a challenge at the MIREX conference, which has useful information about relevant datasets.

- https://music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/2020:Automatic_Lyrics-to-Audio_Alignment
- https://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/2019:Automatic_Lyrics-to-Audio_Alignment
- https://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/2017:Automatic_Lyrics-to-Audio_Alignment
- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/firefliesqn/zalo2022-lyric-aligment

The classical approaches to this problem is using Hidden Markov Models (HMM) on top of an acoustical model. In recent years it is more common to use neural network based approaches. The two can also be combined.

Here are some example code repositories.

- https://github.com/georgid/AlignmentDuration
- https://github.com/SwagLyrics/autosynch
- https://github.com/jhuang448/LyricsAlignment-MTL

Unfortunately, none seem to be mature ready-to-use solutions.

In Speech Processing the related process of aligning a text transcript (without timestamp) with speech is often referred to as a *Forced Aligment* task. And while conceptually the process is quite similar, spoken voice and singing voice is different, and the amount of complex background noise is much higher for music - meaning that speech-oriented models often do not work well.

An alternative to Lyrics Alignment (which requires having the appropriate lyrics) is *Automatic Lyrics Transcription* - where the lyrics is found from the song itself, and does not need to be provided separately.